# AnythingSlider - changing width via CSS causes slider to collapse or not display properly in Safari & Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, jquery-plugins, cross-browser, anythingslider, safari

I am re-writing my question based on new data:

I'm using the AnythingSlider to organize a single-page site into content panels.

The slider works, with all the defaults settings, in Safari/Chrome and FF.  I restyled the navigation and a few aesthetic details, and the slider still works perfectly in all three browsers (I haven't checked IE yet).  As soon as I change the width, however, the entire slider disappears in Safari & Chrome.  It looks great in FF!

I feel like I've tested it upside-down and sideways and no matter what I do, the moment I bump the width to 1000px, it disappears.

Here are things I've tried:

- Adding a container div (wrapping the slider ul), setting its width to
  1000px, and setting my slider ul to 100%.
- Setting the slider ul width and leaving all the panels at width: 100%;
- Setting the slider ul width AND all of the relevant interior items (panels, content div)
- Setting the width and height for all of my images

Since it seems to all boil down to the width attribute, I won't bother posting the code, but please let me know if you'd like to see any of it anyhow!  I feel like this must be very simple and I'm just missing what's in front of my nose...any help or ideas are hugely appreciated!

Comment: Do you still have the same problem when you use `$(document).ready()` instead of `$(window).load()`? Also is the CSS being loaded at the top of the page, before the js?

Comment: Hi -- sorry, I didn't get an alert for your question!  Yes, I just switched to the window.load method to see if it would solve the issue in Safari, and yes also the CSS is loaded on top, before the JS.  I actually think I've narrowed the problem down to a matter of width, and it's even more aggravating...for some reason the width seems to just collapse in Safari.  I can see pieces of the content, but never a whole panel.  In FF it works absolutely perfect!

Comment: Are you setting the `expand` option to `true`? Have you seen the [main width only](http://proloser.github.com/AnythingSlider/expand.html) demo, or [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/Cm479/1431/) that expands in both width and height.

Comment: I did try the various options of expand, as well as the resizeContents and resizePanel just to be sure, and still the problem persisted.  However, I found a workable solution, which I just posted as an answer!  Thanks so much for taking the time to comment/guide my sleuthing.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved!  I am assuming because I seem to be the only one with this issue that it has something to do with the setup of other divs on the site, but here's what I did to fix the issue:

Change this:

```
/* Overall Wrapper */
.anythingSlider {
display: block;
overflow: visible !important;
position: relative;
}
```

To use position: absolute instead.

I realized the issue when I inspected the divs in Safari and found the slider positioned normally, but the panel window ducking off the screen by about 400px. Anyhow--the behavior was strange (and specific to the webkit browsers) and I couldn't find a really logical reason for Safari to do it, but this workaround seems perfectly valid and now everything looks great in FF, Safari, and Chrome.  On to IE!